# Cannot use "connect" in pivot attribute, "Array to string conversion" occurs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have two tables `Element` and `Measurement` with a many-to-many relationship, and an `ElementMeasurement` pivot table that contains an optional attribute `template_id`, which is a foreign key to another `Element` entry.

I have my Models defined as follows:

```php
class Measurement extends Model {
    public function elements(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Element::class)->using(ElementMeasurement::class)->withPivot('template_id');
    }
}

class Element extends Model {
    public function measurements(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Measurement::class)->using(ElementMeasurement::class)->withPivot('template_id');
    }
}

class ElementMeasurement extends Pivot {
    public function element(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Element::class);
    }

    public function measurement(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Measurement::class);
    }

    public function template(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Element::class, 'template_id');
    }
}
```

and my GraphQl schema as follows:

```
type Element {
    id: Int!
    measurements: [Measurement!]! @belongsToMany
    pivot: ElementMeasurementPivot
}

type Measurement {
    id: Int!
    elements: [Element!] @belongsToMany
    pivot: ElementMeasurementPivot
}

input MeasurementInput {
    name: String
    elements: ElementMeasurementInput
}

type ElementMeasurementPivot {
    template: Element @belongsTo
}

input ElementMeasurementInput {
    connect: [ConnectElementMeasurement!]
}

input ConnectElementMeasurement {
    id: Int!
    template: ElementBelongsTo
}
```

I can query the following without issue:

```
{
    measurements {
        id
        elements {
            id
            pivot {
                template {
                    id
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so I know it understands the pivot, but if I try to use a mutation to connect an `Element` to `template_id`, with this:

```
mutation {
    createMeasurement(input: {
        elements: {
            connect: [
                {
                    id: 1
                },
                {
                    id: 2
                    template: {
                        connect: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    )
}
```

I get an "Array to string conversion" error. If I don't add the `template` field, it works, and if I tell my schema that it's a simple `Int` (with then `template: 1`), it also works (but it's ugly).

I don't get why that isn't working.

Comment: have you tried with `{id:2 pivot:{template:{connect:1}}}`

Comment: @N69S that doesn't work, it says the field is not defined, which makes sense. Also it doesn't match how pivots are officially supported: https://lighthouse-php.com/5/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#storing-pivot-data